# Is it possible to use two sets of stator blades after each set of rotor blades in an axial compressor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, compressors

I am currently designing an axial air compressor for a project, and I require the stator blades to reduce the velocity from 50m/s to 2.5 m/s in each stage of the stator. This requires a ratio of the areas to be 20. Hence, the circumferential gap between the edges of consecutive blades need to have a ratio of 20 throughout to be able to achieve the same. The blades start at a radius of 30mm and end at 50mm. This makes the ratio of 20 seem difficult to achieve.

Hence, I was wondering if it would be possible to divide the ratio of 20 into two stages of stator blades, one of ratio 4, and one of 5, hence achieving a more practical design. However, I have not seen such a thing done anywhere.

I believe it would make sense because the stators essentially convert kinetic energy into pressure energy, and hence the different stages shouldn't matter much.

However, I am struggling to understand how the air would behave at the interface of the two stators. There would be a sudden change in area at that point, which is something I don't understand how the behavior would be in.

Comment: Two sets of blades will generally be less effective than combining the two into a single stator.  Gaps are opportunities for air to flow backwards.  Multi stage devices generally alternate rotor- stator, and often have a 'stator' at the inlet even if it is only to stop big things from getting in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely missing the point of how an axial compressor operates. Let's say you design it so the axial velocity everywhere in the machine is a constant 2.5 m/s. The area of the flow will reduce in proportion to the density increase. All of the velocity change will occur in the transverse plane as changes to swirl velocity. So the rotor adds about 50 m/s of swirl to the flow and the stator converts about 50 m/s of swirl kinetic energy into PV work. The cross-section changes are whatever you want them to be for cost and convenience.

Comment: The profile of the rotor blades will also cause a significant increase in the axial velocity of the flow, right? So, the diffuser like arrangement of the stator would help in converting that axial velocity to pressure too, right? I am not clear on how the stator converts the 50m/s swirl flow to PV work. Is it not similar to a diffuser? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: That is the idea behind radial compressors. The stator lies outside the rotor and can exploit centrifugal compression. In the radial compressor, the added velocity is still swirl velocity, but there is a radial component as well. As the flow exits the rotor radially, you get compression from centrifugal force and then slow the swirl with a stator. Now there is no centrifugal force so the flow can be ducted back towards the axis and next rotor without loosing the pressure it gained. Axial compressors run with small percentage changes to flow speed.

Comment: Centrifugal compressors can work with much lower induction velocities and higher percentage changes to the flow speed in each stage.

Comment: *The profile of the rotor blades will also cause a significant increase in the axial velocity of the flow, right?* This is undesirable. It causes thrust loads on the shaft bearings. If the rotor blades look like a parabola looking end on, and the speed is correct, you just get added swirl and no thrust or drag.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation has made it much clearer for me now.